# Java Multithreading waiting state

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I have a `Java`  program like this:

```
List<Callable<String>> todo = new ArrayList<Callable<String>>();  
for(;;) {
    todo.add(new ParallelCall(id,name));       
}
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
List<Future<String>> returnList = es.invokeAll(todo);
es.shutdown();
try {
    es.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
}
catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
for(Future<String> fut:returnList) {
    if(fut.get()!=null) {
        entries.add(fut.get());
    }
}

public class ParallelCall implements Callable<String> {
    public ParallelCall(Integer id,String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String call() throws Exception {
        String result=someFunction();
        return result;
    }
}
```

This code is executing fine. I logged the number of threads currently executing.I found only very few and executor is not taking advantages of ideal cores. There is waiting state for some threads,so it will take more time to complete when the "todo" list becomes large.

Is there any way to speed up the process?

Comment: You can use ThreadPoolExecutor instead of newFixedThreadPool where you can set maximumPoolSize to an essentially unbounded value such as Integer.MAX_VALUE, you allow the pool to accommodate an arbitrary number of concurrent tasks.

Comment: Just because some threads are waiting doesn't mean that the program will take more time to complete. All your parallel tasks are competing for some shared resources (CPU, memory, network, database?), and just throwing more threads at the problem won't magically make the code faster (it's usually the opposite). If your tasks are CPU-bound, for example, having a number of threads equal to the number of CPU cores has a good chance of making the code faster than with 100 or more threads. Threads cost memory, and switching between threads takes time.

Comment: That said, just using newCachedThreadPool() instead of newFixedThreadPool() will allow having an arbitrary number of threads.

Comment: Now you changed the code. The posted code has an infinite loop, so it won't work. And your tasks don't do anything except returning null, so you'd better use a simple loop to execute them: using threads will make things much slower.

Answer (score 0):

Read up on [Amdahl's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law).

An excerpt:

> The speedup of a program using multiple processors in parallel
>   computing is limited by the time needed for the sequential fraction of
>   the program. For example, if a program needs 20 hours using a single
>   processor core, and a particular portion of the program which takes
>   one hour to execute cannot be parallelized, while the remaining 19
>   hours (95%) of execution time can be parallelized, then regardless of
>   how many processors are devoted to a parallelized execution of this
>   program, the minimum execution time cannot be less than that critical
>   one hour. Hence the speedup is limited to at most 20×.

You'll need to find some more parts of your system that can be processed in parallel. Simply increasing the number of threads will have no effect on the execution speed. In fact creating, destroying threads is an expensive processes. Also, since most OSs use a round robin technique to give each thread a fair chance, the OS will spend a considerable amount of time switching between threads. This will further degrade performance.